# req.isAuthenticated is not a function after refactoring middleware

Tags: node.js, passport.js

working on a site where users can make posts and comments. I am using Node with Passport for authentication and everything worked fine, but after I put the middleware in a seperate file, the create new post page and edit comment page give out TypeError: req.isAuthenticated is not a function. The middleware file is connected correctly since other pages load just fine, but those two cause problems...
The middleware code:

```
let middlewareObj = {};

middlewareObj.checkPostOwnership = function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req);
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){

        Post.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCampground){
            if(err){
                res.redirect("/campgrounds")
            } else{
                if(foundPost.author.id.equals(req.user._id)){
                    next();
                } else{
                    res.redirect("back");
            }};
        });
    } else{
        res.redirect("back");
    }
}

middlewareObj.checkCommentOwnership = function(res, req, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        Comment.findById(req.params.comment_id, function(err, foundComment){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect("back");
            } else{
                if(foundComment.author.id.equals(req.user._id)){
                    next();
                } else{
                    res.redirect("back")
                }
            }
        });
    } else{
        res.redirect("back");
    }
}


middlewareObj.isLoggedIn = function(res, req, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect("/login");
}

middlewareObj.isAdmin = function(res, req, next){
    if(req.user.admin === true){
        next();
    } else{
        res.redirect("/");
    }
}

module.exports = middlewareObj
```

Code for the pages that don't load

```
const express = require("express"),
router  = express.Router(),
Post = require("../models/post"),
middleware = require("../middleware");

router.get("/posts/new", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    res.render("posts/new")
});

router.get("/posts/:id/edit", middleware.isLoggedIn, middleware.checkPostOwnership, function(req, res){
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundPost){
        res.render("campgrounds/edit", {campground: foundPost})
});
```

Comment: Since you have `if(req.isAuthenticated()){..` in middleware.isLoggedIn why are you doing the same check again in middleware.checkPostOwnership? Also which middleware does the error come from? isLoggedIn or checkPostOwnership?

Comment: It comes from isLoggedIn

Comment: Are you sure that you initialize passport before you mount the router to app? Something like `app.use(passport.initialize())` before `app.use(the_router)` Would be useful if you add that part to your question.

Comment: Do I have to do that in the middleware file too? I have it in my app.js file, but not in here...

Comment: No, only in app.js